# How to NOT automatically convert my single quotes to &#39;

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi I have a hyperlink in asp.net that I want to dynamically create. I also add additional attributes like onmouseover to call a javascript function. My problem is that instead of setting my attribute to

```
onmouseover="myJSFunc('param')"
```

it converts it to

```
onmouseover="myJSFunc(&#39;param&#39;)".
```

Any ideas how to get this to work in ASP.NET C#? Thanks!

Ryan

EDIT:

These controls are in a repeater. This is what I have in my code behind;

```
hypNav.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "myJSFunc('" + divNav.ClientID + "')");
```

Comment: Is this directly in the template content, or is it inside a server-execute block (`<% %>`)?  If the latter, show the assignment.

Comment: Please post code of generating control.

Comment: Added the code from my code behind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be .Net 4.0 issue. [Check it out](http://forums.asp.net/p/1554455/3818604.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Tried using \' instead of ' ?

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and it's doing the same thing. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `MyControl.Attributes.Add()` in your code behind.

Comment: Hi! That's what I'm doing. The problem is that when you look at the HTML source, instead of having ('), i see &#39. And that's why my javascript call don't work.