# single quote is creating issue in jquery. Prints &#39;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is

```
var subject = $("#subjectText").val();
$("#subjectText").val("Re: " + subject);
```

where `$("#subjectText").val()` is `"MyMessage' My'Message"`

but while showing it to the user `$("#subjectText")` is shown as `"MyMessage&#39; My&#39;Message"`

What could be the best js solution for this?

Comment: How do you 'show it' to the user?

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue. Here works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/2NTbm/

Comment: You need to encode it in your server-side code. Which server-side technology you are using?

Comment: But the question is why value is encoded??? OP didn't provide enough info

Comment: Cannot be reproduced http://jsfiddle.net/UzV4n/

Comment: I also can not reproduce it on jsfiddle but let me try again... I am using grails server side & gsp/js client side.

Comment: there are issues reported here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330121/how-to-not-automatically-convert-my-single-quotes-to-39
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775330/using-single-quotes-escaping-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping and unescaping the text. Here is an example using your string and field:

```
var subject = escape($("#subjectText").val());
$("#subjectText").val(unescape("Re: " + subject));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EgheK/

Answer (score 0):

I am using grails. This is solved by adding 'decodeHTML()' to subjectText on server side.

Answer (score 0):

you are not allowed to use ' in the value.
you can do this to fix the issue:

```
var subject = $("#subjectText").val().split("&#39;").join(" ");
```